How to call ReadJsonAsync() from static class to another class
I have a static helper class which reads a Json file, which I need to call inside another public class and return 200 response code with JSON filepath as response.
JSON is a static file. just I'm trying to learn how to return the response code with JSON file which i read
Code for Helper.cs:
public static class Helper
{
  
public static async Task<string> GetRequestBody(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    string body;
    if (httpContext.Request.HasFormContentType)
    {
        body = JsonSerializer.Serialize(httpContext.Request.Form.ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        // Create StreamReader And Starting Reading The Request Body.
        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true);
        // Assign The Stream Content To The Payload Object
        body = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    return body;
}
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = "path/to/your/file.json";
        var jsonData = await ReadJsonFileAsync(filePath);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonData);
    }

    public static async Task<string> ReadJsonFileAsync(string filePath)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}

Code snippet Employeerecord.cs:
public class Employeerecord : IEmployeerecord 
{
    public Task<List<Domain.Models.EmployeeRecordData>> GET_Employeerecorddata(int employeelist, int employeeId) 
    {
        // How to call the ReadJSonFileASync from Helper class here
        // also return 200 code with Json filepath response
    }
}


That sounds like you actually want a database. For starters, maybe a local single-file db like SQLite. Keeping Data in text files (which json is, in the end) is beyond clunky.

Unrelated: If you cannot move away from json files, you may want to consider deserializing from streams directly: JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync Method

Minor but better practice from the start: Your naming is really off. Convention-wise as well as semantically. A "XyzRecord" usually is the name of the abstraction of one data row. To have it be actually the DataAccess and XyzRecordData be the row would be confusing (imho). Of course you can settle on your own project-language and semantics, but I'd recommend not chasing waterfalls.

"return 200 response code with JSON as response" - are you talking about an http endpoint? You really need to reconsider json-files in that case.

The question is unclear as it is. Nothing prevents you from calling the static method. Doing so from inside Employeerecord is simply wrong though, because you have to hard-code the path. Besides, JSON isn't a database. You have to load and parse the entire file even if you want a single item. Might as well just deserialize everything into a List<EmployeeRecord> and use that list

Employeerecord is a class which couldn't directly return the 200 with the Json filepath response, do you mean you want to read this json file inside a MVC controller or else?

@Brando Zhang - I'm struck with how to approach. If you could share your approach using controllers will learn and will try to implement

Michał Turczyn's solution is one of the right way, using the minimal API is also a good way, you could refer to the answer below. If we using the MVC or else, we still need create a new web application and create the controller for it.

First you have to make the GET_Employeerecorddata method async, then you can call the Helper.ReadJsonFileAsync method like:
public class Employeerecord : IEmployeerecord
{
    public async Task<List<Domain.Models.EmployeeRecordData>> GET_Employeerecorddata(int employeelist, int employeeId)
    {
        // Call the ReadJSonFileASync from Helper class
        string filePath = "path/to/your/file.json";
        string json = await Helper.ReadJsonFileAsync(filePath);
    }
}

Also make sure you add the appropriate using statement to include the namespace the Helper.cs class belongs to.

I tried this way but I was getting this error message The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

@Jeevitha then you didn't make the method async. The async keyword allows you to use await within the method.

@Jeevitha read my answer again, you need to make the GET_Employeerecorddata method async.

I am starting to think that OP has much deeper problems than the specific one at hand. After question edit, it turns out they seem to be looking for an http endpoint implementation. Which goes way above their head right now. I don't see how SO can help with that, though.

What you are asking is quite broad, but I think I can give minimal information that should get you started.
First of all, looks like you are looking for some endpoint that would return data from the file.
To create such endpoints (HTTP endopints), you need to create web applicaiton, which in .NET you can do by createing one of ASP.NET Core apps. For simplicity we can go with Web API, leaving frontend out of the picture.
So, create new project of type "ASP.NET Core Web API" (with dotnet CLI it would be just dotnet new webapi).
There you will have Program.cs that you will modify in order to define your endpoint, it should look like this:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

var summaries = new[]
{
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    var forecast =  Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi();

app.Run();

record WeatherForecast(DateOnly Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary)
{
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}

We will remove all weather related data that comes in template.
Instead, we will define our method to read a file and adjust endpoint to use it. Here are changes:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/get-json-data", () =>
{
    var filePath = "path/to/your/file.json";
    var jsonData = await Helper.ReadJsonFileAsync(filePath);
    return jsonData;
})
.WithOpenApi();

app.Run();

Useful reference: Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core
